# return rows with duplicate pairs across columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
visitor guest   location year
person1 person2 memphis 1994
person1 person4 detroit 2008
person2 person1 oakland 2006
person4 person1 chicago 1993
person3 person1 oakland 1998
person5 person6 detroit 2001
```

I am trying to write a python program that goes through the csv and if there is a visitor + guest that matches a guest+visitor it returns the entire row, like this…

```
visitor guest   location    year
person1 person2 memphis 1994
person1 person4 detroit 2008
person2 person1 oakland 2006
person4 person1 chicago 1993
```

I'm new to python. What I’ve got so far is this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(“visitors.csv")
df2= df[df.duplicated([‘visitor’, ‘guest’], keep=False)]
```

but this is just giving me back the list if ’visitor’ + ‘guest’ are repeated, not if ‘guest’ + ‘visitor’ is the same as ‘visitor’ + ‘guest.’

what i’m trying to do seems to be a variation on this: 
[return rows with unique pairs across columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173949/return-rows-with-unique-pairs-across-columns)

but this code:

```
df2 = df.loc[:, [‘visitor’, ‘guest’]].apply(sorted, axis=1).drop_duplicates()
```

is dropping the duplicates (and just giving me ‘visitor’ and ‘guest’ columns), instead of keeping them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a boolean mask like this:

```
mask = df[['visitor', 'guest']].apply(sorted, axis=1).duplicated(keep=False)
```

Then index on it:

```
df2 = df.loc[mask]
```

Here, `mask` is a Series of booleans that is True wherever the first two columns (order-agnostic) are duplicated somewhere else:

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

and is valid to pass to `.loc[]`, as a means of "filtering" down to True cases.

Comment: It doesn’t @piRSquared. Not exactly sure why

Answer (score 1):

Using the 'visitor' and 'guest' columns as two-level multiindexes, combine the two versions of the dataframe:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['visitor', 'guest'])
df2 = df.set_index(['guest', 'visitor'])
```

If a row has no match, there will be a NaN in the combined dataframe, which you filter out with `.dropna()`:

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).dropna()[[0,1]].reset_index()
result.year = result.year.astype(int)
#   level_0  level_1 location  year
#0  person1  person2  memphis  1994
#1  person1  person4  detroit  2008
#2  person2  person1  oakland  2006
#3  person4  person1  chicago  1993
```